# Select order by letter with number in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have records like this:

```
LEGO 9
LEGO 4
LEGO 5
LEGO 7
LEGO 12
LEGO 13
LEGO 14
LEGO 15
LEGO 10
LEGO 11
LEGO 3
LEGO 1
LEGO 2
LEGO 6
LEGO 8
```

I want them to be sorted ASC

```
LEGO 1
LEGO 2
LEGO 3
LEGO 4
LEGO 5
LEGO 6
LEGO 7
LEGO 8
LEGO 9
LEGO 10
LEGO 11
LEGO 12
LEGO 13
LEGO 14
LEGO 15
```

When I use this statement query below, sort is not correct:

```
SELECT * FROM WA_LEG_TBL_LINES ORDER BY LINENAME ASC

LEGO 1
LEGO 10
LEGO 11
LEGO 12
LEGO 13
LEGO 14
LEGO 15
LEGO 2
LEGO 3
LEGO 4
LEGO 5
LEGO 6
LEGO 7
LEGO 8
LEGO 9
```

Is there any wrong with the statement? I want to order it by `LINENAME ASC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how string sorting works.

If you have text `LEGO` in all the rows in the column, you can remove and cast the result to number and sort by it.

```
select *
from WA_LEG_TBL_LINES
order by cast(replace(linename, 'LEGO ') as number);
```